# Javascript running on mobile safari whilst iphone is locked

Tags: jquery, iphone, web-applications

My webapp is currently sending an AJAX request every 5 seconds. Is it possible to allow it to continue doing this even when the iPhone is locked?

At present is seems like the javascript is paused when the phone is locked and resumed when it's unlocked again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire application (mobile safari) will pause itself when it goes into the background.
What you're asking is not possible on IOS unless you roll your own app.

Comment: Thanks - that completely answers my question!